# Having 24 gigabit ethernet ports cisco switch in gns3

Tags: gns3

I need a 24 port gigabit ethernet cisco switch with 2 fiber ports in gns3. An example of this switch is the Cisco SGE2000 switch, i found out that the gns3 only provides only their default etherswitch router which only provides fastethernet ports. So can i emulate a switch like cisco SGE2000 in gns3?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

No you can't. It looks like newer versions of GNS3 support IOSvL2 (shipped with [Cisco VIRL](http://virl.cisco.com)) and you now can setup many standard switch features (spanning-tree, LACP, port-security, ...). But this will not be like a standard 24 port switch running IOS.

And BTW: Cisco SMB Switches do not run IOS, they are quite different.

Comment: So is there no way i can simulate a 24 gigabit port cisco switch in gns3? if so, do you know any network simulators wherein i can achieve this? PT  also doesn't work.